# What plant is this? A kind of Thyme?

Tags: rosemary, spices

It's similar a bit to Summer savory, but definitely, it's not and it has a different shape, scent. It is grows crawling rather than standing up as Rosemary does. The leaves are rather small, Rosemary ones are twice as big. It is a thyme variaty? For sure it is not oregano. I've used plant identification at identify.plantnet.org but with no good results.

[image: Not oregano]

The remains of the flowers look like this
[image]

Another picture:
[image]

New images with starting flowers

[image]
[image]

Is it Thymus serpyllum (Breckland thyme) , Thymus praecox , Thymus pulegioides or Thymus longicaulis ?

Flowers:
[image]

Fully in flower neighbouring oregano and rosemary on the right with busy bees :
[image]

Comment: Not oregano, thyme nor rosemary - what makes you think its actually a herb of some variety? If it is, I don;t recognise it as such... are the leaves fragrant?

Comment: @Bamboo: why not thyme? GERIKO: Is steam quadrangular or round? Do you remember the flowers/.

Comment: Hi  @giacomo   yes the leaves are fragrant. The stem is round. Right now it does not have any flowers. I might have seen some time ago some small  tiny light rosy flowers, but I'm not sure. Somebody who bought it told that has an Oregano scent and got it as Oregano, strange, but I don't think that.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi - I grow various thymes, this doesn't look even vaguely like any of them...

Comment: @Bamboo: ok, I should invite you at my home. I have various Thymes that vaguely look like as in the photo. Never with so long stems, but they are lften creepy and with long stolons. So for me it is a to me unknown species of Thyme.

Comment: I find it little bit similar to this Thymus pulegioides Some leaves have little side-whiskers. Thymes have more than 200 varieties.

Comment: [link](https://bit.ly/2FwBKBm)

Answer (score 1):

It looks quite a lot like winter savoury, *Satureja montana*, to me. Have you tried tasting it (assuming you're willing to take the risk that it is edible)? Thyme and rosemary have quite distinct flavours. Winter savoury is peppery and slightly bitter.

EDIT: I've added a picture of a plant that was sold to me as 'winter savoury' by a good garden centre in the UK (but I don't have the Latin name from the garden centre). I think it looks a lot like your pictures. My plant tastes peppery, but I could also believe that it had some thyme flavour to it (but that would also fit with the description of *Satureja montana*).

However, I agree that the flowers here look more like other pictures online of *Thymus pulegiodes* - *Satureja montana* can have purple flowers but in other pictures online they appear to be distributed all the way up the stem (more akin to rosemary). So perhaps my plant was misdescribed by the garden centre, or perhaps the same common name is sometimes applied to both plants.

On the whole, I would tend to agree that it is *Thymus pulegiodes*.

[image]

Comment: Hi Izy! Thank you for your answer. I've updated my post with a picture of its flowers. Its flowers don't look like winter savory flowers. Yes I've tested it and has a spicy flavour with a slight peppery tinge. Its flowers are akin to that of Large Thyme [Thymus pulegioides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thymus_pulegioides)

Comment: @GERIKO, I have edited my answer. I am inclined to agree with you. If you think you have solved your own problem then you could post a reply to your own question, explaining the steps you went through to identify it, and then accept your own answer.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer. I let the question open. I have Summer Savoury also, this was the first plant I definitely took off the list. Thanks for the update.